# Cannot find text file that is saved on desktop for my twitter bot

Tags: python, twitter, chatbot, tweepy, txt

```py
# my_twitter_bot.py

import tweepy
import time
# NOTE: I put my keys in the keys.py to separate them
# from this main file.
# Please refer to keys_format.py to see the format.
from keys import *

# NOTE: flush=True is just for running this script
# with PythonAnywhere's always-on task.
# More info: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AlwaysOnTasks/
print('this is my twitter bot', flush=True)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

FILE_NAME = 'last_seen_id.txt'

def retrieve_last_seen_id(file_name):
    f_read = open(file_name, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(f_read.read().strip())
    f_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_last_seen_id(last_seen_id, file_name):
    f_write = open(file_name, 'w')
    f_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    f_write.close()
    return

def reply_to_tweets():
    print('retrieving and replying to tweets...', flush=True)
    # DEV NOTE: use 1060651988453654528 for testing.
    last_seen_id = retrieve_last_seen_id(FILE_NAME)
    # NOTE: We need to use tweet_mode='extended' below to show
    # all full tweets (with full_text). Without it, long tweets
    # would be cut off.
    mentions = api.mentions_timeline(
                        last_seen_id,
                        tweet_mode='extended')
    for mention in reversed(mentions):
        print(str(mention.id) + ' - ' + mention.full_text, flush=True)
        last_seen_id = mention.id
        store_last_seen_id(last_seen_id, FILE_NAME)
        if '#dumbduck' in mention.full_text.lower():
            print('found #dumbduck', flush=True)
            print('responding back...', flush=True)
            api.update_status('@' + mention.user.screen_name +
                    ' I don't like you human.', mention.id)

while True:
    reply_to_tweets()
    time.sleep(15)
```

[This](https://github.com/ykdojo/twitterbotsample) is the code which I have pulled from online.

And the error I am receiving:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: `last_seen_id.txt`
```

The txt file last_seen_id.txt is saved in the same folder as `my_twitter_bot.py`.

I don't understand why it is not able to read the `last_seen_id.txt` file.

Comment: Try specifying the full file path

Comment: The file won’t exist the first time you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

when using `with open()` specify the full file path if the file is not in your current working directory